# How to show this kind of variable data with range slider

Tags: javascript

Data

```
amount: 10
subscriber_count: 2500

amount: 20
subscriber_count: 5000

amount: 30
subscriber_count: 10000

amount: 40
subscriber_count: 25000

amount: 50
subscriber_count: 50000

amount: 60
subscriber_count: 100000

amount: 70
subscriber_count: 200000

amount: 80
subscriber_count: 300000
```

Range slider should move according to the subscriber count first time its 2500 second time it should be 5000 and so on and print the amount with respect to the subscriber count. For the first 3 its double but after the third one, its 25000 thats where it messes up. What kind of calculation should i do or is there another way to do it
code

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<script></script>
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2500" max="300000" value="2500" class="slider" step="2500" id="myRange">
  <p>Subscriber: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <p>Price: <span id="demo"></span>10</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways you could do it. You should try one, if it doesn't work out, then you can ask why. We avoid questions where you ask others to write code for you, but we can fix your code. Your question is also unclear about what is expected. Suggestion: create a map where they keys are 10,20,30... and the values are 2500, 5000, 10000 and use that to display the values (you may need the inverse map)

Comment: I just came across very same problem with range slider... Still can't find a solution for it though. It looks like each browser not only renders sliders differently, but updates them differently. In my case I was working in Angular and range slider was not updated as you change its parameters (min, max, value) dynamically... Couldn't find the way to force update it though...

Comment: When (and if) datalists are widely supported you can use a datalist to add labels to each step. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Adding_hash_marks_and_labels

Note that this isn't supported by any browsers yet, but I'll leave a pointer to it here in case it does become supported in the future

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup an array containing the values you want to be displayed:

```
var myValues=[2500,5000,10000,25000,50000,100000,200000,300000];
```

Afterwards modify your slider to increase/decrease in steps of 1 (and set it's max to your array's length-1)

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="7" value="0" class="slider" step="1" id="myRange">
```

and finally output the values from the array instead of the slider's actual value

```
output.innerHTML = myValues[0];
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = myValues[parseInt(this.value)];
}
```

Comment: I want to use arrow ()=>{ function instead of function() this.value would not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to get the closest amount. You can make the same with subscriber count

```js
var arr = [{
    amount: 10,
    subscriber_count: 2500
  },
  {
    amount: 20,
    subscriber_count: 5000
  },
  {
    amount: 30,
    subscriber_count: 10000
  },
  {
    amount: 40,
    subscriber_count: 25000
  },
  {
    amount: 50,
    subscriber_count: 50000
  },
  {
    amount: 60,
    subscriber_count: 100000
  },
  {
    amount: 70,
    subscriber_count: 200000
  },
  {
    amount: 80,
    subscriber_count: 300000
  }
]


var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = getClosest(this.value, 'subscriber_count');
  output2.innerHTML = getClosest(this.value, 'amount');
}

function getClosest(val, key) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr.subscriber_count - parseInt(val)) < Math.abs(prev.subscriber_count - parseInt(val)) ? curr : prev);
    })[key];
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<script></script>
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2500" max="300000" value="2500" class="slider" step="2500" id="myRange">
  <p>Subscriber: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <p>Price: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the existing answer?

Comment: @JuanMendes The input "range" generated is not the same. It's shorter at the start and larger at the end. The actual answer provide an constant input "range".

Comment: @JuanMendes It's juste a style & UX  differences with the other answer

Comment: I see, I think  obsucre's answer with the input being 1-7 makes more sense, but it depends where the OP wants the stops to be (equidistant or according to the values). By the way, you should always explain your answer, specially when there are existing answers that are very similar. Also, using reduce to find an item is a waste of cycles and a not semantic use of the function, you should stop iterating once you find something, using a function like `Array.find`